# TcpServer send string TcpClient (delphi)

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, tcpserver

How to make receipt of the message component TcpSlient?

**CLIENT:**

```
procedure TForm1.client1Receive(Sender: TObject; Buf: PAnsiChar;
  var DataLen: Integer);
var
s: string;
begin
s := client1.Receiveln();
while s<>'' do begin
if s='CDOPEN' then
mciSendString('Set cdaudio door open wait', nil, 0, handle);
if s='CDCLOSE' then
mciSendString('Set cdaudio door closed wait', nil, 0, handle);
s := client1.Receiveln;
end;
end;
```

**SERVER:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
st: AnsiString;
begin
st:='CDOPEN';
TcpServer1.Sendln(st);
end;
```

The client does not work((

Comment: Does not work is not specific enough. In what way does it not work. What has your debugging told you?

Comment: Program is going fine. Run the client (127.0.0.1, 1488) to run the server (127.0.0.1, 1488). Click to open the CD-ROM, and nothing happens

Comment: What does your debugging tell you? Does communication happen? Are messages sent? Are messages received? Why do you not check for errors when calling `mciSendString`?

Comment: This concept looks to me weird. It should be client that sends something to server, not vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in `TClientSocket` and other socket library implementations, the `OnReceive` event in `TTcpClient` DOES NOT trigger when there is new data available to be read.  It is only triggered when `ReceiveBuf()` is called (which `Receiveln()` uses internally).  So there is no point in calling `Receiveln()` inside of `OnReceive` since you have to be in a reading operation to get `OnReceive` triggered in the first place.  The `Buf` parameter provides the data that has already been read and will be returned to the caller when `OnReceive` exits.  So `OnReceive` acts more like an `OnAfterRead` event instead.  To do what you are attempting, you would need to call `Receiveln()` periodically, such as in a timer or loop.  There is no event to tell you when to read.

FYI, `TTcpClient` (and `TTcpServer` and other related classes) [has been removed](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C++Builder_XE6#Web.Win.Sockets_Unit_Converted_into_Product_Sample) in XE6.  So you are better off using `TClientSocket` or a third-party component from Indy, ICS, Synapse, etc.